# GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null) errors out

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import, oledb

I'm getting an error when reading the columns of a specific excel workbook in C#, using the following code:

```
        DataTable dtCols = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            dtCols = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, null);
        }
```

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$_'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

My sheet name is name "Sheet1" but apparently the system is trying to read the columns of one of the hidden tables in the schema - notice there's an underscore at the end of that sheet name.

How do I prevent that line of code from erroring out? Is there a way to take advantage of the restrictions parameter to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the worksheet in the method call otherwise it doesn't know which columns to load. It is loading Sheet1$ as the default which doesn't exist in your spreadsheet.

try,

```
    var list = new List<string>();
    DataTable dtColumns = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new string[] { null, null, workSheetName, null });
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtColumns.Rows)
        list.Add(dr[3].ToString());
```